# locking down document section in docusign

Tags: asp.net, docusignapi

I want the document section to be locked down while using embedded docusign feature.It needs to be like read-only mode.User should not be able to change the document or add multiple documents.
Kindly,suggest the way to achieve it in docusign rest api.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that you don't want free form signing enabled for the envelope?

In that case, just add one or more fields to the envelope yourself, (or via the API), and the signers won't have the opportunity to add their own fields.

Comment: No.I want to prevent the user from changing document or uploading mutiple documents after getting into embedded view.We want to lock entire document upload section.

Comment: When I do embedded signing, the signer does not have the ability to change the document or upload documents....are you doing embedded signing or embedded sending? See the recipe for embedded signing: https://github.com/docusign/esignature-recipes-python

Comment: Embedded sending.Even though it redirects to signature screen.user can click on back button and change the uploaded document.Is there a way to block it.

Comment: I don't know what you want to accomplish. Please either submit a new question or add much much more detail to your question (you can edit your question). Do you want the person to send out an envelope for signing or do you want the person to sign the envelope?